# Is my method of online banking from work secure? Chromebook + 4G + VPN

Tags: encryption

I need to do various online banking activities from work, about once a month.  I have a Chromebook that I use exclusively for this task. I don't navigate to any other websites on it, or install any other apps beyond chrome on it.

I have a smart phone with a large data-plan that allows me to create a wifi hot-spot, which I plan to connect to.  It uses 4G LTE(in Canada) with WPSA2 PSK security and a password I choose.

My phone also has a VPN feature provided by my subscription to BitDefender, which I plan to enable while I do the banking.

I am not an expert in this area, so I was hoping for some feedback on this setup.

- Is this a secure way to do banking from a public area?  Any flaws?
- Is the 4G hotspot that my phone will create secure? Or can other
  users of 4G see my device on the network and hack it or eavesdrop on
  data that it sends and receives?
- Will my Bit Defender VPN add any extra security?

Comment: The VPN likely won't have any effect on the hotspot, due to the way the phone's routing works. You can confirm this by checking your public IP address before and after connecting the phone to the VPN.

Comment: Checking from the tethered device, that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a secure way to do banking from a public area?

Yes. Possibly overkill for most people, to be honest.

> Any flaws?

Oh, probably. Nothing jumps out as obviously bad, but there is always room for improvement. For instance: you didn't mention any form of 2FA. Make sure if your bank offers it, that you take advantage. Also, if you are able to tether via USB or even Bluetooth instead of a hotspot, it might be slightly stronger. But it's probably not a major problem now anyway.

> Is the 4G hotspot that my phone will create secure?

Assuming that you use WPA2 for the hotspot, and set a good (preferably random) password, you should be fine. It will be difficult for anyone else to crack the encryption on the connection in a reasonable time even if they capture all the traffic, provided the password is strong enough.

> Or can other users of 4G see my device on the network and hack it or eavesdrop on data that it sends and receives?

Yes, 4G security is not as strong as we would prefer. [4G is vulnerable to modification of your network traffic or snooping on the domains visited](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/06/lte-wireless-connections-used-by-billions-arent-as-secure-as-we-thought/), although I get the impression the actual data exchanged with a server (not under the attackers control) remains confidential. Your bank *should* be using https which will protect from malicious modification of the data exchanged with the server, and prevent you contecting to a spoofed bank server, however it will not protect from an attacker determining you are visiting the bank's website.

> Will my Bit Defender VPN add any extra security?

Possibly. If someone manages to crack the WPA (or you use a crappy password for it), or sets up a malicious 4G base station, then the VPN will add another layer of encryption which they will not be able to crack.

However VPN only encrypts the connection between your computer and the VPN endpoint. The VPN endpoint then connects you to your bank, over the plain Internet, without any further protection. So your connection to your bank should be over https anyway. This is probably all the protection you need as it will protect the entire connection end to end. Someone snooping on your wifi hotspot or 4G connection would be stopped by HTTPS already, even without a VPN.

What a VPN can add, is making sure nobody can attempt a "man in the middle" attack if your bank's https is poorly configured, and it can also hide the fact that you're communicating with the bank at all from anybody listening on your wifi or 4G. Note a VPN cannot hide your connection for people on the wider Internet,:just the local network (wifi in your case, or an attacker on your phone), from someone attacking you nearby over 4G, and from your phone carrier itself.

Comment: "Others can definitely see it. But with WPA2 and a strong password, eavesdropping will take a very long time." The particular question was about the mobile network, but you're talking about WiFi here.

Comment: Oops! I misread that part. I'll fix in a bit.